# Git pipeline reuse container

Tags: git, docker, automated-tests, pipeline

Is there any way to reuse containers from previous stages?

What i am trying to achieve with Git Pipeline:
My application is an orchestrator for workflows and source code. Said Source code is what is changed and needs to be tested.

- using custom docker runner which is using image with prepared application(empty) i use entrypoint to load fresh source code and configuration and run validity check. Loading and validating takes up to 10 minutes.
- i want to reuse container in previous stage and do more complicated tests and for each test i want to use separate stage.

Main problem is that Git throws away container from first stage (and all stages) after this stage is done.

My workaround for now is to use shell runner and use docker-compose, entry points and docker exec commands to achieve what i want.
I do not want prepare new image with source code inside, because it is not a "production like" and i need even the action of importing source codes tested.

thanks

Comment: What you can do to reuse your docker container, Write `dockerfile` in an optimized way. If after every build dockerfile have dynamic changes then docker will recreate container.
What you can do, create stages for docker image. at least you can create a separate image which remains same every time of build and move the dynamic values vich cause change in docker file to the end of file so that docker can use its cache.

Comment: If you could give your dockerfile then someone can have a batter opinion

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand. You mean you can store and reuse layers after container is ran?

Comment: Can you post your `dockerfile` ?

Comment: i added it to the question

Comment: So this is what eating up your time `ADD mz-package.tar.gz /opt/mz` copy and extract applicatoin to a directory

Comment: have you have a close look, which step of docker builder took more time ?

Comment: Is this dockerfile is manually created or by some automated tool like `jLib` ?

Comment: oh i know what you mean. dockerfile is not the problem that takes time. Problem is action of importing source code to container which is done in the entrypoint and cant be optimized, since the application is slow.